# How to best read and UTF-8-decode byte buffers?

Tags: c#, encoding, utf-8, stream

I have a [`Stream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.aspx) that produces [UTF-8](http://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) encoded strings. The strings represent XML documents that I need to parse. The stream is obtained from a [`TcpClient`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.aspx).

Suppose I read the stream into buffers of size 64 (a little small, I know). Passing these 64 byte buffers directly to the string decoding step could fail because some UTF-8 encoded characters may be split along the 64 byte boundary. The buffer may end with the first two bytes of a character and the next buffer has the last byte for this character.

What I do now, is concatenate buffers until I perform a read that doesn't read the full 64 bytes, indicating that I have read to the end of something (in my case, an XML document). However, once in a while, an XML documents I read ends exactly at the 64 byte boundary. In such a case, I do not know I can pass the byte array to the decoding step (and I need to wait for the next document).

I realize I can lower the chances by increasing the buffer size. However, a small chance always remains that it happens. I could also increase the buffer size such that any XML document I encounter will fit, but I just wonder whether there is another solution, somehow detecting from the byte stream where the character boundaries are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right about the problems and pitfalls.

The solution already exists: wrap a `StreamReader` around your stream and use `Read()` and `ReadLine()`

If you do want a DIY solution you'll have to look at the Encoder state properties. Beyond my capabilities.

Comment: It looks like `StreamReader` does exactly what I want. I remember having looked into that class but I can't remember why I discarded it. Can't use `ReadLine()` because there are no line breaks, it's a contiguous stream of XML documents.

Comment: What do you mean by `Encoder` state properties? I know the `Encoder` and `Decoder` classes but am not sure what state properties you're referring to.

Comment: @Ronald Don't overlook XmlReader. Those state properties are in a related encoder/encoding class, forgot which one.

Comment: `XmlReader` won't work. I get a contiguous stream of XML documents and there is no way to have `XmlReader` accept more than one document as input (since this would be invalid XML).

Comment: But doesn't the XmlReader _stop_ after each document? That would be nice & useful.

Comment: I tried using `XmlReader` but it assumes that the stream you provide contains one document. I could not find any 'continue-with-next' functionality. So when it encounters the opening tag of the next document it throws an exception.

Comment: `XmlReader` is a pull parser (it pulls data from the Stream). Find a push parser instead, then you can push your TCP chunks into the parser as you receive them.  Since the TCP data has multiple documents, you can push a custom opening tag into the parser first, then start pushing the documents one after the other, and they will be treated as second-level opening tags instead of top-level documents.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that your approach is theoretically flawed, even if it should always work correctly in practice: there is no guarantee that a successful read of less than (buffer size) indicates that an XML document has been received in its entirety. The TCP stack is fully within its rights to give you back the document one byte at a time. Increasing the buffer size to several KB should cause this problem to manifest itself.

Addressing the above flaw properly will also solve your current issue: prepend some kind of fixed-length header (e.g. 8 bytes) that contains the following document's length before each XML document in your TCP stream. You will always know when you have read a full header (because it's fixed size), and given the header you will know when you have received the whole document.

Comment: Hm, you're right that it's a flawed approach, hadn't realized that it could go wrong anyway (although in practice it will probably always work). Unfortunately, I have no influence on the sending side. Otherwise, a header would be a good solution, both to solve my initial problem and as a boundary between XML documents.