# TCPClient Reading Stream

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sockets, netty, tcpclient

I have a Netty game server that sends JSON messages with a null delimiter. I had an AS3 client communicating correctly with that server but our new Unity client can't communicate properly probably due order of the messages being sent. Sometimes I get exceptions on parsing JSON strings, especially with long messages. I have tried different buffer sizes but nothing changed.

```
try {
    _tcpClient = new TcpClient();
    await _tcpClient.ConnectAsync(_host, _port);
    _isListening = true;

    Debug.Log("Connected...");
    UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(DispatchConnected());

    Byte[] bytes = new Byte[BufferSize];
    StringBuilder partialMessage = new();
    while (_isListening && !_stopRequested) {
        if (_tcpClient != null && _tcpClient.Connected) {
            using (NetworkStream stream = _tcpClient.GetStream()) {
                if (stream.CanRead) {
                    try {
                        int bytesRead;
                        while ((bytesRead = stream.Read(bytes, 0, BufferSize)) > 0) {
                            string bufferMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRead);

                            // Append the buffer to the existing partial message
                            partialMessage.Append(bufferMessage);

                            // Check if the partial message contains the termination character
                            int terminateIndex;
                            while ((terminateIndex = partialMessage.ToString().IndexOf(TerminateCharacter)) != -1) {
                                string completeMessage = partialMessage.ToString(0, terminateIndex);
                                Debug.Log("R: " + completeMessage);
                             UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(DispatchServerMessage(completeMessage, true)); // <-- This is where I convert to JSON

                                // Remove the processed portion from the partial message
                                partialMessage.Remove(0, terminateIndex + 1);
                            }  
                        }
                    }
                    catch (IOException ioException) {
                        Debug.LogError($"IOException: {ioException.Message}");
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception) {
                        Debug.LogError(exception);
                    }
                }

                
            }
        }
        else {
            Debug.Log("TCP Client is not connected!");
            ClientDisconnected();
            break; // Break out of the loop when the client is not connected
        }
    }

    // Process any remaining partial message after the loop
    if (partialMessage.Length > 0) {
        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(DispatchServerMessage(partialMessage.ToString(), true));
        partialMessage.Clear();
    }
}
catch (SocketException socketException) {
    if (socketException.ErrorCode == 10061) {
        // Debug.LogError("Connection refused!!!");
        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(DispatchConnectionRefused());
    }
    else {
        UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(DispatchConnectionInterrupted());
    }
}
catch (IOException ioException) {
    UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(DispatchConnectionInterrupted());
    // UnityMainThreadDispatcher.Instance().Enqueue(DispatchConnectionRefused());
}
finally
{
    _stopRequested = true; // Ensure the thread stops even if an exception occurs
    _tcpClient?.Close();
    _clientReceiveThread = null;
}
```

When I look at the errors, I can see that SOME of the messages come in an unordered way. For example, lets say the server sends three messages with null delimiter `Hello\0Socket\0World`, my client receives Socket -> Hello -> World.

Is there a better way to handle JSON messages? What could be wrong here? If it was a server issue, the AS3 client would also have errors.

Below is the netty initializer code.

```
ChannelPipeline pipeline = socketChannel.pipeline();
pipeline.addLast("timeout", new IdleStateHandler(ServerSettings.MAX_IDLE_TIME_IN_SECONDS, 0, ServerSettings.MAX_IDLE_TIME_IN_SECONDS));
pipeline.addLast(new DelimiterBasedFrameDecoder(1024 * 1024, Delimiters.nulDelimiter()));
pipeline.addLast(new StringDecoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8));// (2)
pipeline.addLast(new StringEncoder(CharsetUtil.UTF_8)); // (1)
pipeline.addLast(new SimpleTCPHandler()); // (3)
```

Thanks

Comment: tcp is designed to prevent this, udp is not. So this doesnt make sense. tcp is supposed to guarantee arrival and order by the time you see it. at a network layer level they can become out of order but they get junked

Comment: I would be concerned about the decoding of strings. I think you may split 2+ byte characters in buffer boundaries, possibly causing incorrect decoding. I would expect this to cause issues with finding the terminator, since you would need to decode character by character. A length prefixed protocol would be easier to decode, or one with a binary payload.

Comment: @JonasH should I rewrite parsing char by char? Our previous AS3 client parses char by char. It's much safer I guess.

Comment: Changing the server protocol is the last option for me because I need to update old clients too.

Comment: I do not have sufficient experience with text based protocols to provide concrete recommendations. I just know Unicode and networking can both be complex, with plenty of ways to make mistakes, and your code looks suspect to me. I strongly prefer protocols like http/gRPC where there all the complex details are handled by the libraries.

Comment: I would *strongly* suggest you don't try implementing this yourself. Instead use a higher level protocol such as gRPC or SignalR. Your buffer needs to be able to hold a at least three JSON messages, or better you can join together a sequence of arrays.

Comment: @Charlieface can you elaborate more on what to avoid? Reading char by char?

Comment: Char by char works to an extent but will be very slow. I was suggesting you read into a buffer, then check if you have an end of message character and parse all that. Concatenate each blob together using a queue of buffer arrays, dropping any arrays that have been fully processed. Like I said, it's complex and there are much better protocols out there. Also UDP is unreliable, so you may get a partial message. If using UDP you need to guarantee that a message will not be fragmented.

Comment: @Charlieface I understand there are much better alternatives but it's hard for me to change that at the moment. Our AS3 Clients work great, probably I have some problems with parsing JSON. How's that different from the code I have provided? I am also reading into a buffer and looking for the terminator string. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Charlieface I am using TCP. Edited my answer, putting Netty code.

Comment: @Charlieface can you see any errors in my message parsing code? I still get some parsing problems.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the comments, you need to improve:

1. **Proper multi-byte character handling**:

   Decoding issues can come from a multi-byte character being split across buffer boundaries. Make sure the buffer does not inadvertently split a character, which could corrupt the message and complicate finding the terminator. That might involve inspecting the last few bytes of the buffer to make sure they do not start a multi-byte character without finishing it.

   ```cs
   // Assuming UTF8 encoding
   bool IsPotentialMultiByteSequenceStart(byte b) {
       // Checks if the byte is the start of a multi-byte sequence in UTF-8
       return (b & 0xC0) == 0x80;
   }

   // Use this function to determine if the last byte of your buffer might be the start of a multi-byte character
   bool MightSplitMultiByteCharacter(byte[] bytes, int bytesRead) {
       if (bytesRead == 0) return false;
       return IsPotentialMultiByteSequenceStart(bytes[bytesRead - 1]);
   }

   // You might need to adjust your reading logic to account for this possibility
   ```
2. **Efficient message parsing**:
   The strategy of reading into a buffer and then parsing for message terminators needs refinement to make sure it handles edge cases, like partial messages or messages that span multiple buffers.
   If messages are consistently larger than the current buffer, consider adjusting the buffer size dynamically or making sure that your logic can handle messages that span multiple reads.

   ```cs
   // Assuming BufferSize is appropriately sized and TerminateCharacter is defined
   while (_isListening && !_stopRequested && stream.CanRead) {
       int bytesRead = stream.Read(bytes, 0, BufferSize);
       if (bytesRead > 0) {
           // Handle potential multi-byte character split
           int endIndex = bytesRead;
           while (endIndex > 0 && MightSplitMultiByteCharacter(bytes, endIndex)) {
               endIndex--; // Adjust endIndex to make sure multi-byte characters are not split
           }

           string bufferMessage = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(bytes, 0, endIndex);
           partialMessage.Append(bufferMessage);

           ProcessMessages(partialMessage); // Process complete messages within partialMessage
       }
   }

   // That function processes and clears processed messages from the StringBuilder
   void ProcessMessages(StringBuilder partialMessage) {
       int terminateIndex;
       while ((terminateIndex = partialMessage.ToString().IndexOf(TerminateCharacter)) != -1) {
           string completeMessage = partialMessage.ToString(0, terminateIndex);
           Debug.Log("Received: " + completeMessage);
           // Dispatch the message for further processing
           partialMessage.Remove(0, terminateIndex + 1);
       }
   }
   ```

That aligns with [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7186847/6309), which suggests a DIY solution.

---

> My TerminateCharacter is `\0` If sent buffer ends with an extra character '`a`' for instance, last bytes will be `\0\0061`.
> What will happen to the extra '`a`' character in this solution? Won't that character removed from the rest of the buffer?
>
> I am also confused about `return (b & 0xC0) == 0x80;` this part.
> Will that work in my terminate character?

Regarding handling the extra character '`a`' after the termination character:
When the buffer ends with a termination character followed by an extra character `a` (e.g., the bytes are `\0` followed by the ASCII representation of `a`), the `a` character is preserved for the next message processing cycle. The `ProcessMessages` function processes up to the termination character, removes the processed message including the termination character from `partialMessage`, and any subsequent characters (like `a`) remain in `partialMessage` for processing during the next cycle.
That means the extra `a` character will not be removed or lost; instead, it will be the starting point of the next message to be processed.

The expression `return (b & 0xC0) == 0x80` is used to identify continuation bytes in UTF-8 encoded characters. [UTF-8 characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) can range from 1 to 4 bytes, where the first byte indicates the number of bytes in the character, and subsequent bytes (continuation bytes) follow the pattern `10xxxxxx`. That method checks if a byte is a continuation byte by masking it with `0xC0` (which isolates the two most significant bits) and comparing the result with `0x80`. If the result is true, the byte is a continuation byte, meaning it is part of a multi-byte character that started in previous bytes.

That check is important for making sure that you do not split a multi-byte character across reads from the buffer. However, it does not directly impact the handling of your termination character `\0`. The termination character `\0` (null character) is a single-byte character in UTF-8, not a continuation byte, so this specific check (`(b & 0xC0) == 0x80`) is not used to identify or handle the termination character itself. Instead, it helps prevent the accidental splitting of multi-byte characters that could corrupt the parsing of your UTF-8 encoded messages.

Comment: thanks for the detailed explanation. My TerminateCharacter is `\0` If sent buffer ends with an extra character 'a' for instance, last bytes will be `\0\0061`. What will happen to the extra 'a' character in this solution? Won't that character removed from the rest of the buffer?

I am also confused about `return (b & 0xC0) == 0x80;` this part. Will that work in my terminate character?

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will integrate these into my code and test the results. Hope this fixes it :)